# Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have a project built in visual studio 2013 environment with the Db built using EF 5 code first. 
I have had my APIs working fine for a long time but all of a sudden I started to get this error that says:

> Unable to update database to match the current model because there are pending changes and automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable automatic migration.

when I try to reach the end points of my APIs. I tried adding a new migration and then updating the database but still got the error. I then drop my entire database and recreated with EF. The end points of my APIs started working fine but then again I started getting this error on the web page. I have automatic migration set to true in the configuration file. I really have no idea why this is happening over and over. It's getting me really frustrated. 
Here's the full stack trace of the error:

> > 
>
> [AutomaticMigrationsDisabledException: Unable to update database to
>   match the current model because there are pending changes and
>   automatic migration is disabled. Either write the pending model
>   changes to a code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.]
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Upgrade(IEnumerable`1
>   pendingMigrations, String targetMigrationId, String lastMigrationId)
>   +579    System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.UpdateInternal(String targetMigration) +445
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.<>c__DisplayClassc.b__b() +13
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.EnsureDatabaseExists(Action
>   mustSucceedToKeepDatabase) +422
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.DbMigrator.Update(String
>   targetMigration) +78
>   System.Data.Entity.Migrations.Infrastructure.MigratorBase.Update() +12
>   YourTimeSite.Global.ApplyDatabaseMigrations() in
>   c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\YourTimeSite\YourTimeSite\Global.asax.cs:55
>   YourTimeSite.Global.Application_Start(Object sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\Users\Ahmed\Desktop\YourTimeSite\YourTimeSite\Global.asax.cs:32
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to update database to match the
>   current model because there are pending changes and automatic
>   migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a
>   code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.]
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.EnsureAppStartCalledForIntegratedMode(HttpContext
>   context, HttpApplication app) +9966013
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.RegisterEventSubscriptionsWithIIS(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context, MethodInfo[] handlers) +118
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.InitSpecial(HttpApplicationState state,
>   MethodInfo[] handlers, IntPtr appContext, HttpContext context) +172
>   System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.GetSpecialApplicationInstance(IntPtr
>   appContext, HttpContext context) +352
>   System.Web.Hosting.PipelineRuntime.InitializeApplication(IntPtr
>   appContext) +296
>
> [HttpException (0x80004005): Unable to update database to match the
>   current model because there are pending changes and automatic
>   migration is disabled. Either write the pending model changes to a
>   code-based migration or enable automatic migration. Set
>   DbMigrationsConfiguration.AutomaticMigrationsEnabled to true to enable
>   automatic migration.]
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9947380 
>   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context)
>   +101

Comment: See my answer to a similar question here https://stackoverflow.com/a/52973524/470014

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's not really enough here to diagnose the root cause of the issue, but generally, you will only get that error if you're database is out of sync with your entity classes in some way. If you truly believe it is not, you can disable this exception from occurring by deleting the `_MigrationHistory` table from your production database. At that point, EF will treat the database as existing, and no longer prompt you to migrate it. Instead, you'll get exceptions only when it find unexpected/missing columns, or other SQL errors resulting from schema desynchronization. In some ways, that's better though, as if there actually is something off, you'll have better idea of exactly what is off, rather than being broadly told that you need to migrate.

However, removing the migration history table means that you will then be responsible for keeping it synced up if you do make changes to your entity classes. Generally, that's not a problem, anyways. It's a poor idea to run migrations against a production database, anyways, so this actually forces you to explicitly update the schema when necessary, hopefully using proper change management policies.

Comment: There are some weird things happening in my database that make no sense. I deleted _MigrationHistory table in the db and when I connect to the APIs, I get the message that says 'xyz' table is already present in the database. So I deleted that table and refreshed the tables tree and the table came back. The API conected fine after that. All this started happening after I tried to remotely debug my server. I have done it many times before but this never happened. I'll have to carefully look into this issue. Your answer worked for me though.

Comment: I had changed the name of my migration files manually, looking at the table `__MigrationHistory`, I realized it did not match anymore so I changed it manually in there and it worked

Answer (score 20):

I had a lot of trouble with this but the answer for me was to exclude intermediate database migration items that altered tables which were already created with those alterations.  If I knew a bit more about what I am doing here, I think I would follow the advice above on the DbContext settings.

Running update-database produced the same errors, but:

- adding an empty migration (via PM) and then update_database worked

`add-migration EmptyMigration`

Then run

```
update-database
```

At this point the migrations ran without error.

- To wit, several migrations required exclusion from the project (not understanding how the CodeFirst project had already created these migrations and thus they were unneeded and therefore, "exclude"-able).
- Project Migrations included intermediate steps that updated the table structure that EntityFramework had already applied (Entity Framework newbie- I am - working with CodeFirst examples from udemy - MVC5 course)
- What began as "Unable to create explicit migration for..." (VS2019)
- Then "No pending explicit migrations.Found invalid data while decoding."
- Followed instructions to delete obj folder and then clear the cache from Nuget without any result.
- Next, tried to delete and recreate the database with an empty database (I'm running developer version of SQL Server but Express would be the same) using SSMS.  This part may or may not have been needed.
- Brought the project up and noticed it was Net Framework 4.5 so updated to 4.7.  Again, not sure if it was needed.  The sample project was built for Community Edition 2013.
- Restarted the project (VS2019)
- Performed two steps above and everything is working now.

Comment: The two steps in this answer totally fixed this issue as described in the OP. 100+

Comment: Worked for me.. Thanks

Comment: Sometimes, if you have not the database truly synchronized (maybe you changed some manually in the DB), the `add-migration` command could generate a _non-empty_ migration. In this case, you can simply comment (or delete) the migration content.

Comment: Hello, @Jamie, this empty migration solves the exception error. However, whenever someone make a new migration and I just pull the new code for the project, I will receive the error again, no matter if it was running fine before. Any clue why is this the case?

Comment: Relevant MS link for the need of Empty migration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/migrations/teams

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing anything manual in your DbContext implementation, my situation may help you.

In my case, in my DbContext construction sequence, I was manually performing migration checks.  In other words, I was utilizing `Database.SetInitializer`.

In a few short lines, I am initializing a context and messing with `SetInitializer`.  As part of that, I am also playing with the Initialization Strategy `MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<TContext, TMigrationsConfiguration>`

Lastly, my generic types, which are generic implementations I developed, were different levels of abstraction.  I tested amongst using *typing* between:

- DbMigrationsConfiguration, EF's basic DbContext Configuration
- BaseConfiguration, My abstract base DbContext Configuration
- `<U>`, allowing the user to pass in their implementation of my base.

In the end, it turns out the different `SetInitializer` calls and `DbContext` instantiations needed to all be using `<U>` or, probably, just the same level of abstraction of the same classes.

**TLDR** - Check if you're using `SetInitializer` with generics, and make sure your generics are all 100% exactly the same, not bases/subclasses of each other.

Answer (score 2):

In your database initializer turn `AutomaticMigrations` to **true** then revert it back to **false**, this would fix the issue:

```
internal class MyDatabaseInitializer : MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyDBContext, MyConfiguration>{

}

internal sealed class MyConfiguration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<MyDBContext>{

    public MyConfiguration(){
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with is error recently.

The problem was that the migration was declared in a namespace not matching the assembly name, and EF could not find it at run time.

Answer (score 0):

One of the causes is of this error is merging code with an additional migration to your working copy.

If you add a migration, the command writes to the console:

> The Designer Code for this migration file includes a snapshot of your
> current Code First model.

It is this designer code that will be inspected to determine whether there are any pending model changes. If two different migrations where created in two different branches, they cannot be merged correctly into a single working copy, without additional work.

My resolution is as follows:

1. Update the database to the last common migration. (This might
   require checking out an old commit, without merged migrations).
2. Merge the branches.
3. Update the database to one of the migrations.
4. Delete the other migration (keeping a copy, if manual modifications had been made).
5. Use `Add-migration` to scaffold a new migration.

   - This migration should have the same `Up()` and `Down()` methods as before.
   - However, its designer file will be different, because the changes after the other migration had been applied.
6. Restore any custom migration code.
7. Update the database to see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

This can be because you need to build between steps. For example, if you are using the `dotnet exec` method of invoking the ef6 tools manually, you will not get automatic builds. The migration you just added will then not yet be present in your assembly, and EF will think there are still pending changes. Once you build it should see that things are up to date and be able to apply the migration to the DB.

Answer (score 0):

In configuration.vb, change from false to true in the following line of code:
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true